# Print all possible combinations, given a specific number format

Tags: python, algorithm, security, cryptography, brute-force

I am interested in trying to "brute force" all of the possible combinations of a string that takes the format "##-######" where the first two characters are numbers 0-9, followed by a hyphen and than six more numbers 0-9.

All I want to do is to print these to a text file or to the console. 
This is a learning exercise for me, and not for school or work.

I am not looking for code samples, per-say but instead reference materials that talk about guessing patterns.

I prefer python, but can work in most languages.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for code with no work done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('file.out', 'w') as output:
    for n in xrange(100000000):
        s = "{0:08d}".format(n)
        output.write(s[:2] + '-' + s[2:] + '\n')
```

… But be aware that that's a *lot* of combinations, it's possible that you'll run out of memory, and if not anyway the resulting file will be *huge* and the program will take a lot of time to finish. Brute force is not a good idea here.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an FYI, that would be 10^8 (100,000,000) combinations. You are very quickly going to run out of memory.

Anyway, besides the memory thing...

```
from itertools import product

["%02d-%06d" % (i[0], i[1]) for i in product(range(100), range(1000000)]
```